# Use XSLT replace function with external CSV look up table

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xpath, replace

I currently have an XSLT that searches across multiple strings using XPath in order to find certain words and if they match replace with the alternate word. This is highlighted with the 'old' and 'new' tags at the beginning of my current XSLT.

XSL EXAMPLE

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:reps>
  <rep>
  <old>neighbor</old>
  <new>neighbour</new>
  </rep>
 </my:reps>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('')/*/my:reps/*"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="series_synopsis_long/text() | series_synopsis_medium/text() | series_synopsis_short/text() | season_synopsis_short/text() | season_synopsis_medium/text() | season_synopsis_long/text() | episode_synopsis_short/text() | episode_synopsis_medium/text() | episode_synopsis_long/text() | episode_keywords/text() | season_keywords/text()" name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not($vReps/old[contains($pText, .)])">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pReps"
         select="$vReps[contains($pText, old)]"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="multiReplace">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:param name="pReps"/>

  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pReps">
       <xsl:variable name="vRepResult">
         <xsl:call-template name="singleReplace">
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pOld" select="$pReps[1]/old"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pNew" select="$pReps[1]/new"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$vRepResult"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pReps" select="$pReps[position() >1]"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="singleReplace">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:param name="pOld"/>
  <xsl:param name="pNew"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pText">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $pOld))">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $pOld)"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$pNew"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="singleReplace">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $pOld)"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pOld" select="$pOld"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pNew" select="$pNew"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to be able to manage an external look up table externally in a csv document (or other suitable format) to keep the code removed from a table that will be updated regularly by many users. The idea is that if values are listed in columns with headings of 'old' and 'new' that i should be able to link these as variables into my existing xslt sheet...

Any guidance on this would be appreciated as so far csv is proving more problematic to navigate with xslt as first thought! My thoughts are do i need to use a key() function perhaps or to convert the csv to an xml first and then process the xml as my external look up every time i need to call a transform?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 can't process plain text files like CSV files so CSV does not appear to be a good choice, unless you know you use an XSLT 2.0 processor where `unparsed-text` is available.

Comment: I can utilise Saxon as a 2.0 processor my xsl does not need to be in 1.0. If i utilise the unparsed-text function would i still be able to navigate via columns of 'old' and 'new' to fit with my variable names currently?

Comment: Perhaps the use of tokenize() will allow me to break the unparsed-text into the two columns allowing me to fit into the match and replace function i want in the xsl? Am i on the right track?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use XML as your external file format? You'd have less "moving parts" that way.

Comment: Yes as described it is a table that will be updated regularly by users who are not familiar with xml syntax/structure

Comment: CSV is not a table either. I presume your users will be using some application that can export a .csv file? Most of such applications (e.g. Excel) can also export XML.

Comment: This sounds like you are recommending that i do this as per my thought expressed at the bottom of my first question. if i have a table (excel) that i then call a convert to xml function prior to calling this xsl each time i need to do a transform that that is the easiest way to go down?

Comment: I am saying that if you export from Excel as XML instead of .csv, then you don't have to manipulate CSV in the XSLT. So that's one (error-prone) step less in the process.